# You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to useraccount without a default - django

Tags: django, django-models

i have this models and when i try to write `python manage.py makemigrations` it say

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to useraccount without a default; we can't do that (the database needs somet
hing to populate existing rows).
```

my models.py :

```
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Profile_Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=False) # new
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id or not self.slug:
            super(UserAccount, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            self.slug = slugify(f"{self.user}")
        super(UserAccount, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_image(self):
        if self.Profile_Image and hasattr(self.Profile_Image, 'url'):
            return self.Profile_Image.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

what is the error here

Comment: Deleting the last migration file(or all files) in your migrations folder and retry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django, `ManyToManyField` and `OneToOneField` fields are not allowed to have a  `NULL` value.

You have this error possibly because you had some data previously(in your database) which did not follow this rule. But now that you're changing the database rules, going by the structure of your model, your database expects that all data in that table(with respect to the model) follows this rule.

What you could do to remedy this is to delete all your migration files that this model generated(found in the `migrations` folder inside the app's directory).

Thereafter, rerun your migrations, and then delete the data from that table that didn't follow this rule. To protect the integrity of the data though, (assuming this is working production data) you might prefer to set a default value on your field which will be applied to all the existent data.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because Django is confused about what to do with records that existed before you made this change to your model. Assuming that your project is in development, you should consider removing your migrations and run them after you're done coding for your model, so everything is at sync. Btw, migration files for each app exist in a folder named as migrations in that app's folder.